# Java not recognizing null value in jSonObject

Tags: java, android, null

I have a jSonObject with key values pairs and i want to parse it to ContentValues. During the parse i want to detect wether the value is null, as you can see in the picture the value is null, but still it does not get catch by the if statement. Because it's a json and might be pasing null as string i tried to use value.equals("null") but neither it worked.

[image: debug info]

```
if ( value == null | value. equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
    DO SOME CODE
}
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: `value == null | value. equals("null")` if value is `null` not a null string won't `value. equals("null")` throw a NPE ? I think it should be written as `"null".equals(value)`

Comment: Did you print the value of **value** in console? Try **System.out.println("Value:"+value+":");** and show me the exact output.

Comment: Yes, i did. System.out.println("value is "+value) prints `value is null`. when it should print `value is`, that's why i tried the `value.equals("null")`

Comment: Try to print the exact line what I have mentioned above and tell me the output

Comment: Then any one of these condition will be true **value == null || value. equals("null")**. But it didn't right?

Comment: Right. That should make it, but it does not 8o

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42279/discussion-between-ajeesh-and-xabier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to retrieve values from jsonobject is using getString() method. So you must use **value = jsonObject.getString(columnName);** to assign the value for **value** variable. Then you need to check the condition as

```
if ( value == null || value. equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) 
{

}
```

Comment: That made it, what i do not understand yet is why it did not stop in one of both statements `(value == null || value.equals("null")`, `get` is supposed to return an object, so it should stop at least on `value == null`, still, if for some reason it was parsing as string it should stop in `value.equals("null")` . Anyway, this solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Your first "OR" is just a single pipe '|' instead of the double-pipe '||'

```
if ( value == null || value.equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
    DO SOME CODE
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `OR` operator in java can be single pipe or double pipe, if single, and the first statement is true it would not continue checking the next. This way i avoid nullpointer exception.

Comment: @Xabier Sorry, that's close but not correct. the | is the bitwise OR operator, not the logical OR operator.

Comment: @Xabier see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html for reference.

Comment: Well, the Sun Java documentation states if both operands are boolean or Boolean then the result of bit-wise operators is boolean, too. That means that a single-pipe bit-wise OR turns into a boolean OR: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2 ... it still doesn't make sense as OP intended. Using bit-wise OR should be as effective at avoiding NPE as boolean OR. Boolean expressions are evaluated from left to right. When you have an OR'ed two part-expression (A OR B) Java will evaluate the whole as true if A is already true.

Comment: @netinept I tried but same result. It does not stop. Somehow it is parsing the object null as string, inside the `if`, i do `contentValues.put(columnName, ((value==null)? "": String.valueOf(value)))` and it is filling the contentValue as string "null";

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
if ( value == null || value.equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
    DO SOME CODE
}
```

Comment: StringUtils is not by default in android studio. I would prefer to avoid adding additional classes. At least just for checking if a value is null. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try using value.isNullObject() function.  It returns true if the object is NULL.

Comment: value.isNullObject does not exist !?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( value == null | value. equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
    DO SOME CODE
}
```

Though in your case if value is "null" above will turn out to be

```
value == null | value. equals("null")// first condition in if statement --->if(false|true)---> if(true)
```

you are using bit wise OR not logical OR

It should be

```
  if ( value == null || value. equals("null") || tableField.getType() == FIELD_TYPE_NULL ) {
        DO SOME CODE
    }
```

Comment: I tried that as suggested by @netinept but it didn't work. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one `|` in you first condition

Comment: Yes, the `OR` operator in java can be single pipe or double pipe, if single, and the first statement is true it would not continue checking the next. This way i avoid nullpointer exception.